# Android Call Forwarding & Call Conferencing

Tags: android, telephony

Any one can tell me that for android is it possible to handle the Call Forwarding and call Conferencing by coding at application level ?

can we able to forward the incoming call to any other phone number by programatically in android?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found something interesting for you. Have a try with it:

- [Android programming - Call forwarding](http://danielthat.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-programming-call-forwarding.html)

But,call conferencing is not so easy task. You need **CCXML** and should program a conference manager to have a go.See:

- [Is there any API support to make conference calls programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430620/is-there-any-api-support-to-make-conference-calls-programatically-in-andriod)